# HTTP/ JSON Response - Developer Console

Tags: apex, json, callout, developer-console, http

I'm trying to access an object that it is part of an HTTP JSON Response, [this one](http://api.wunderground.com/api/48ba9f7756d42102/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Spain/Sevilla.json). What I want is to access only the `location` object from that response. If I access the full response from the developer console like this.

```
String url ='http://api.wunderground.com/api/48ba9f7756d42102/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Spain/Sevilla.json';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
String responseBody = res.getBody();

system.debug('Weather response: ' + responseBody);
```

I get the full response exactly as the link above. That is fine.
Now I want to access only the `location` JSON object by doing this:

1. **I created one class for this purpose:**

   ```
   public with sharing class WeatherLocation {

   public location location{get;set;}

   public class Location {
       public String country_iso3166{get;set;}
       public String zip{get;set;}
       public String magic{get;set;}
       public String country{get;set;}
       public String wmo{get;set;}
       public String state_name{get;set;}
       public String latitude{get;set;}
       public String state{get;set;}
       public String longitude{get;set;}
       public String city{get;set;}
       public String elevation{get;set;}
       public String full{get;set;}
     }
   }
   ```
2. **I execute a new anonymous code:**

   ```
   String url ='http://api.wunderground.com/api/48ba9f7756d42102/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Spain/Sevilla.json';
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint(url);
   req.setMethod('GET');
   Http http = new Http();
   HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
   String responseBody = res.getBody();
   WeatherLocation.location Wloc = (WeatherLocation.location)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, WeatherLocation.location.class);
   system.debug('WeatherLocation  ' + Wloc);
   ```

**The output that I'm getting:**

> 20:21:59:367 USER_DEBUG [15]|DEBUG|Github user Location:[city=null,
>   country=null, country_iso3166=null, elevation=null, full=null,
>   latitude=null, longitude=null, magic=null, state=null,
>   state_name=null, wmo=null, zip=null]

The response is sending back `null` values for each of the fields I want to use. Anyone knows what it is that I'm missing here. This approach works fine with other JSON responses, do I need to call some other JSON object in order to get access to the location object? Any help will be much appreciated.

payload:

```
  "location": {
    "type": "INTLCITY",
    "country": "SP",
    "country_iso3166": "ES",
    "country_name": "Spain",
    "state": "SE",
    "city": "Sevilla",
    "tz_short": "CEST",
    "tz_long": "Europe/Madrid",
    "lat": "37.38000107",
    "lon": "-5.98000002",
    "zip": "00000",
    "magic": "2",
    "wmo": "WLEEC",
    "l": "/q/zmw:00000.2.WLEEC",
    "requesturl": "global/stations/WLEEC.html",
    "wuiurl": "https://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/WLEEC.html",
    "nearby_weather_stations": {
      "airport": {
        "station": [
          {
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "country": "",
            "icao": "",
            "lat": "",
            "lon": ""
          },
          {
            "city": "Sevilla El Copero",
            "state": "",
            "country": "SP",
            "icao": "LEEC",
            "lat": "37.31000137",
            "lon": "-6.00000000"
          },
          {
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "icao": "LEZL",
            "lat": "37.41999817",
            "lon": "-5.90000010"
          },
          {
            "city": "Moron de la Frontera",
            "state": "",
            "country": "SP",
            "icao": "LEMO",
            "lat": "37.15000153",
            "lon": "-5.61999989"
          }
        ]
      },
      "pws": {
        "station": [
          {
            "neighborhood": "Sea cliff",
            "city": "Seville",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLE12",
            "lat": 37.382401,
            "lon": -5.9761,
            "distance_km": 0,
            "distance_mi": 0
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle General García de la Herranz",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA40",
            "lat": 37.374828,
            "lon": -5.975199,
            "distance_km": 0,
            "distance_mi": 0
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Luis de Montoto",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA36",
            "lat": 37.389091,
            "lon": -5.984459,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 0
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Guzmán el Bueno",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA61",
            "lat": 37.387226,
            "lon": -5.990362,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 0
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Velarde",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA31",
            "lat": 37.384609,
            "lon": -5.997752,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 0
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Sebastián Trujillo",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA47",
            "lat": 37.382309,
            "lon": -5.960624,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Virgen del Monte",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "SP",
            "id": "ISEVILLA44",
            "lat": 37.377792,
            "lon": -6.000916,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Virgen de la Cinta",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA34",
            "lat": 37.372639,
            "lon": -5.99912,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Avenida de la Reina Mercedes",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA71",
            "lat": 37.362957,
            "lon": -5.986244,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Carretera de Carmona",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA67",
            "lat": 37.397945,
            "lon": -5.980408,
            "distance_km": 1,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Avenida Ramón de Carranza",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "SP",
            "id": "ISEVILLA30",
            "lat": 37.371792,
            "lon": -6.002954,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Evangelista",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA75",
            "lat": 37.379345,
            "lon": -6.007031,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle San Vicente",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA57",
            "lat": 37.396194,
            "lon": -5.999093,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Sevilla - Triana",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "SEVILLA",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA13",
            "lat": 37.380402,
            "lon": -6.010914,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Aracena",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA77",
            "lat": 37.384449,
            "lon": -6.010558,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Feria",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA51",
            "lat": 37.40292,
            "lon": -5.99197,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Sevilla - Ronda de los Tejares",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "ANDALUCíA",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "IANDALUC83",
            "lat": 37.380451,
            "lon": -6.013572,
            "distance_km": 2,
            "distance_mi": 1
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Estrasburgo",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA29",
            "lat": 37.348221,
            "lon": -5.979222,
            "distance_km": 3,
            "distance_mi": 2
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Cantina",
            "city": "Seville",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLE3",
            "lat": 37.419109,
            "lon": -5.98512,
            "distance_km": 4,
            "distance_mi": 2
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "www.meteosanjuan.com",
            "city": "San Juan De Aznalfarache",
            "state": "SEVILLA",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA21",
            "lat": 37.360889,
            "lon": -6.030504,
            "distance_km": 4,
            "distance_mi": 2
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Vicente Aleixandre",
            "city": "Tomares",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ITOMARES5",
            "lat": 37.370872,
            "lon": -6.03558,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Profesor Tierno Galván",
            "city": "Tomares",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ITOMARES7",
            "lat": 37.383041,
            "lon": -6.038856,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Ulises",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ISEVILLA59",
            "lat": 37.396545,
            "lon": -5.923732,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Sevilla - Hacienda San Antonio",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "Andalucía",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "IALSEVIL3",
            "lat": 37.379246,
            "lon": -5.917678,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "San Juan de Aznalfarache",
            "city": "San Juan De Aznalfarache",
            "state": "SE",
            "country": "SP",
            "id": "ISESANJU3",
            "lat": 37.350018,
            "lon": -6.029826,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Parque Alcosa",
            "city": "Sevilla",
            "state": "ANDALUC�A",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "IANDALUC53",
            "lat": 37.407822,
            "lon": -5.926668,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "San Juan de Aznalfarache",
            "city": "San Juan De Aznalfarache",
            "state": "SE",
            "country": "SP",
            "id": "ISESANJU4",
            "lat": 37.356781,
            "lon": -6.037522,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Calle Virgen de los Dolores",
            "city": "Tomares",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ITOMARES2",
            "lat": 37.375854,
            "lon": -6.045006,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "Tomares - Aljamar",
            "city": "Tomares",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "ITOMARES8",
            "lat": 37.373432,
            "lon": -6.044942,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          },
          {
            "neighborhood": "La Cartuja",
            "city": "Tomares",
            "state": "ANDALUCíA",
            "country": "ES",
            "id": "IANDALUC181",
            "lat": 37.365551,
            "lon": -6.045215,
            "distance_km": 5,
            "distance_mi": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just deserialize into a `WheatherLocation` instance, not `WheatherLocation.Location`?

Comment: Let me try that Adrian.

Comment: Adrian, that did it. Deserializing into `WheaterLocation` rather than `WheaterLocation.Location` is giving a response back for those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deserialize into the proper type. In this case, that's the top level class (`WeatherLocation`). I stripped out some irrelevant attributes from your payload and it came through clean. Here's the `Execute Anonymous` script I used to demonstrate:

```
public with sharing class WeatherLocation
{
    final Location location;
}
public class Location
{
    public final String country_iso3166, zip, magic, country;
    public final String wmo, state_name, latitude, state;
    public final String longitude, city, elevation, full;
}

String payload = '{"location":{"type":"INTLCITY","country":"SP","country_iso3166":"ES","country_name":"Spain","state":"SE","city":"Sevilla","tz_short":"CEST","tz_long":"Europe/Madrid","lat":"37.38000107","lon":"-5.98000002","zip":"00000","magic":"2","wmo":"WLEEC","l":"/q/zmw:00000.2.WLEEC","requesturl":"global/stations/WLEEC.html","wuiurl":"https://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/WLEEC.html"}}';
WeatherLocation instance = (WeatherLocation)JSON.deserialize(payload, WeatherLocation.class);
system.debug(instance);
```

Comment: @Carlos I didn't catch it myself until my anonymous script threw a compile fail!

Comment: That is one of the dangers of copy/paste :)